# Radeon 5770 running in software mode how to change to hardware after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, radeon

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 from Ubuntu 14.04 it said my graphics card would run in software mode versus hardware mode. It's running loud and my screen resolution isn't 1080p when my monitor is capable of it. I'm just learning linux and could use some help. this is my system
ati radeon 5770 1gb
intel phenom II x4 945
4gb ddr2 800mhz

Comment: See above. The `fglrx` driver was removed in 16.04. You'll have to use the open source `amd-gpu` driver.